# easy way to append mean value using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have data in the following form:

```
ID      Value
Sample1 value1
Sample1 value2
sample1 value3
sample2 value1
sample2 value2
sample2 value3
...
```

I want to append a column with the average of each sample.

I can get the averages as follows:

```
myData %>% group_by(., ID) %>% summarise(., averageValue = mean(Value))
```

But is there an easy way to append or do I need to do some sort of match argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mutate` instead of `summarise`

```
myData %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>% 
      mutate(averageValue= mean(Value))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
myData <- data.frame(ID= rep(paste0('Sample', 1:2), each=3), 
         Value=rnorm(6))
```