# Mean as a window-function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate group means but save them as a vector next to the raw data. Is there an efficient way to do this in `dplyr`?

Original `data.frame`:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  group = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
  value = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
  )

> dat
  group value
1     A     4
2     A     5
3     A     6
4     B     7
5     B     8
6     B     9
```

Desired `data.frame` with full vector of group means:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(
  group = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
  value = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
  groupmeanvalue = c(5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8)
)

> dat2
  group value groupmeanvalue
1     A     4              5
2     A     5              5
3     A     6              5
4     B     7              8
5     B     8              8
6     B     9              8
```

Comment: This might be a better duplicate since it uses `mutate`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657265/easy-way-to-append-mean-value-using-dplyr-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- dat %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(groupmeanvalue = mean(value))

dat
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: group [2]

   group value groupmeanvalue
  (fctr) (dbl)          (dbl)
1      A     4              5
2      A     5              5
3      A     6              5
4      B     7              8
5      B     8              8
6      B     9              8
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
dat$groupmeanvalue <- with(dat, ave(value, group))
dat$groupmeanvalue
#[1] 5 5 5 8 8 8
```

---

Or another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, groupmeanvalue := mean(value), by = group]
```